# How to access values of arguments which is passed in a task with DataProcPySparkOperator operator?

Tags: pyspark, airflow

I want to pass parameters to specific task in my Airflow Dag and access it in my pyspark code. Below is the task definition :

```
run_cmd_arg_test_job= DataProcPySparkOperator(
    task_id='test',
    main='gs://dataprocessing_scripts/testArg.py',
    arguments=['2018-05-07'],
    job_name='test',
    dataproc_cluster='smoke-cluster-{{ ds_nodash }}',
    gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    region='global'
)
```

how can I access value of "arguments" property in main file "gs://dataprocessing_scripts/testArg.py" ?

Comment: Able to access arguments using sys.argv in pyspark code. Please suggest if there is any better approach?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find another way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2]`
`sys.argv[0]` will be filename itself
and `sys.argv[1]` will be '2018-05-07'
Also don't forgot to import sys